# Changing Current Tab Drop Down Menu Color

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the text color of my drop down menu. The drop down text color is based off of the main link text color. When I select that link it changes to the current tab color, but also changes the drop down text color. I was wondering how to make the drop down menu color independent from the main tab text color.

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">

           <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
            <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

           <ul id="nav" class="nav">

               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li class="current"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li><span><a href="portfolio-index.html">Resources</a></span>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="alcoholre.html">Alcohol</a></li>
                    <li><a href="drugsre.html">Drugs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mentalhealthre.html">Mental Health</a></li>
                    <li><a href="suicidere.html">Suicide</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
               <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

           </ul> <!-- end #nav -->

        </nav> <!-- end #nav-wrap -->
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#nav-wrap ul, #nav-wrap li, #nav-wrap a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
}

/* nav-wrap */
#nav-wrap {
position: relative;
font: 15px raleway-heavy, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
float: right;
margin-top: 32px;
margin-right: 20px;
z-index: 99999;
}

/* hide toggle button */
#nav-wrap > a.mobile-btn {
display: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}

ul#nav {
min-height: 48px;
width: auto;

/* left align the menu */
text-align: left;
}
ul#nav li {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
height: 48px;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Links */
ul#nav li a {

/* 8px padding top + 8px padding bottom + 32px line-height = 48px */

display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 11px;
line-height: 32px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
color: #ffffff;

-webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

ul#nav li a:active { background-color: transparent !important; }
ul#nav li:hover > a,
ul#nav li.current a { color: #00b2ee; }

/* adds down arrow */
ul#nav span:after {
width: 0;
height: 0px;
border: 4px solid transparent;
border-bottom: none;
border-top-color: #00b2ee;
content: '';
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
right: 5px;
}

/* Sub Menu
----------------------------------------------------- */
ul#nav ul {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
background: #c7c7c7;
min-width: 100%; 


border-radius: 5px 5px 7px 7px;

/* for transition effects */
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);

-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

/* Third level sub menu
ul#nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;

border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
*/

ul#nav ul li {
padding: 0;
display: block;
text-align: left;

/* for transition effects */
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;

-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

/*On Hover */
ul#nav li:hover > ul { 
opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li {
height: 42px;
overflow: visible;
border-bottom: 1px solid #26272C;
color: #ffffff;
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li:last-child  { border: none; }

/* Sub Menu Anchor links */
ul#nav ul li a {
padding: 6px 15px;
margin: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

add the following at the end of your css script

```
ul#nav ul li a:hover{
color:red;
}
```

Example:

```css
#nav-wrap ul, #nav-wrap li, #nav-wrap a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
}

/* nav-wrap */
#nav-wrap {
position: relative;
font: 15px raleway-heavy, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
float: right;
margin-top: 32px;
margin-right: 20px;
z-index: 99999;
}

/* hide toggle button */
#nav-wrap > a.mobile-btn {
display: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}

ul#nav {
min-height: 48px;
width: auto;

/* left align the menu */
text-align: left;
}
ul#nav li {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
height: 48px;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Links */
ul#nav li a {

/* 8px padding top + 8px padding bottom + 32px line-height = 48px */

display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 11px;
line-height: 32px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
color: #ffffff;

-webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

ul#nav li a:active { background-color: transparent !important; }
ul#nav li:hover > a,
ul#nav li.current a { color: #00b2ee; }

/* adds down arrow */
ul#nav span:after {
width: 0;
height: 0px;
border: 4px solid transparent;
border-bottom: none;
border-top-color: #00b2ee;
content: '';
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
right: 5px;
}

/* Sub Menu
----------------------------------------------------- */
ul#nav ul {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
background: #c7c7c7;
min-width: 100%; 


border-radius: 5px 5px 7px 7px;

/* for transition effects */
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);

-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

/* Third level sub menu
ul#nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;

border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
*/

ul#nav ul li {
padding: 0;
display: block;
text-align: left;

/* for transition effects */
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;

-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

/*On Hover */
ul#nav li:hover > ul { 
opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li {
height: 42px;
overflow: visible;
border-bottom: 1px solid #26272C;
color: #ffffff;
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li:last-child  { border: none; }

/* Sub Menu Anchor links */
ul#nav ul li a {
padding: 6px 15px;
margin: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size: 13px;
}
ul#nav ul li a:hover{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-wrap">

           <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
            <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

           <ul id="nav" class="nav">

               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li class="current"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li><span><a href="portfolio-index.html">Resources</a></span>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="alcoholre.html">Alcohol</a></li>
                    <li><a href="drugsre.html">Drugs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mentalhealthre.html">Mental Health</a></li>
                    <li><a href="suicidere.html">Suicide</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
               <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

           </ul> <!-- end #nav -->

        </nav> <!-- end #nav-wrap -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La7uvd75/) using your code. While hovering over the drop down menu links, the text color changes to the blue as being used on the current menu tab. In case you don't want to use blue on text hover in the drop down menu and want to go with the white text links, just remove "ul#nav li:hover > a," from your code and it'll do the work.

Now your new CSS code should look like :-

```
#nav-wrap ul, #nav-wrap li, #nav-wrap a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
}

/* nav-wrap */
#nav-wrap {
position: relative;
font: 15px raleway-heavy, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
float: right;
margin-top: 32px;
margin-right: 20px;
z-index: 99999;
}

/* hide toggle button */
#nav-wrap > a.mobile-btn {
display: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}

ul#nav {
min-height: 48px;
width: auto;

/* left align the menu */
text-align: left;
}
ul#nav li {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
height: 48px;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Links */
ul#nav li a {

/* 8px padding top + 8px padding bottom + 32px line-height = 48px */

display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 11px;
line-height: 32px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
color: #ffffff;

-webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

ul#nav li a:active { background-color: transparent !important; }
ul#nav li.current a { color: #00b2ee; }

/* adds down arrow */
ul#nav span:after {
width: 0;
height: 0px;
border: 4px solid transparent;
border-bottom: none;
border-top-color: #00b2ee;
content: '';
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
right: 5px;
}

/* Sub Menu
----------------------------------------------------- */
ul#nav ul {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
background: #c7c7c7;
min-width: 100%; 


border-radius: 5px 5px 7px 7px;

/* for transition effects */
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);

-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

/* Third level sub menu
ul#nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;

border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
*/

ul#nav ul li {
padding: 0;
display: block;
text-align: left;

/* for transition effects */
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;

-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

/*On Hover */
ul#nav li:hover > ul { 
opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li {
height: 42px;
overflow: visible;
border-bottom: 1px solid #26272C;
color: #ffffff;
}
ul#nav li:hover > ul li:last-child  { border: none; }

/* Sub Menu Anchor links */
ul#nav ul li a {
padding: 6px 15px;
margin: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

In case you want to use some different color while hovering over the drop down text links, you need to use this code separately in the css :-

```
ul#nav li:hover > a {color:your color name or color code}
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried using that but was using it in the wrong part. I put it in like you said and it is now working! Thank you for your help!